# Is it possible to click the table row and it also clicks button on row?

Tags: jquery

I have table rows with diffrent `<td>`'s. One of them is a Button.

I want that i can click anywhere on the row to make a button click with jquery.
In addition the row should turn green.

currently i have this:

```js
$(".table tr").on('click', function(event) {
  $(this).toggleClass('highlighttask');
  $('button[name="checkbtn"]').click();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table">
  <tr>
    <td>click</td>
    <td>
      <form method="POST" action="main.php" value="<?php echo $zeile['id']; ?>">
        <button type="submit" name="checkbtn">                                          
      Check
      </button>
        <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $zeile['id']; ?>">
      </form>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

If i use `$('button[name="checkbtn"]').click();`

I get this error > Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Comment: You get the error because clicking on your button is clicking on the parent row (which is then triggering the click on your button again).  You need to stop the button 
 click [event propagating](https://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/)

Comment: where should i add the `event.stopPropagation();`?

Comment: to the button click event

Comment: Still gives me the error

Comment: then you've bound it to the wrong event

Comment: I put it inside the `$(".table tr").on('click', function(event) {`with `event.stopPropagation();`

Comment: yep, that's not the button click event, that's the tr click event

Comment: How do i put it into the button click event?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to stop the button click event triggering the tr click event as it will cause a loop that will give you the maximum call stack size exceeded error

```js
$(".table tr").on('click', function(event) {
  $(this).toggleClass('highlighttask');
  $('button[name="checkbtn"]').click();
});

$('button[name="checkbtn"]').on('click', function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();  // stop click bubbling up to parent
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table">
  <tr>
    <td>click</td>
    <td>
      <form method="POST" action="main.php" value="<?php echo $zeile['id']; ?>">
        <button type="submit" name="checkbtn">                                          
      Check
      </button>
        <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $zeile['id']; ?>">
      </form>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

[More information about e.stopPropagation](https://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/)